Where value in column B is listed in column C, column C is a comma-delimited list
I have a SQL table where column C has multiple values in a comma-delimited list. I have been trying to write a query asking if the value in column A is listed in Column B, populate those rows. I have tried CONTAINS and other statments but they either populate none or all of the rows in my table. I then ended up writing out each of the distinct values in column B in a WHERE/LIKE statement however it is pretty lengthy. I am using SQL Server Management Studio. Here is a sample table that shows what my data looks like:



Column A
Column B
Column C




1
apples
apples, oranges


2
oranges
apples, grapes.


3
grapes
oranges, apples



What I am expecting based on this data is to have 2 and 3 populated in my results because for 2 - oranges is not listed in column c and for 3 - grapes is not listed in column c
I am currently using this query to get the results I need however I fear that there may be some values missing if the wildcard characters don't evaluate them all.
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE column_b NOT LIKE '%apples%'
  AND column_c LIKE 'apples%'
    OR
  column_b NOT LIKE '%oranges%'
  AND column_c LIKE 'oranges%'
    OR
  column_b NOT LIKE '%grapes%'
  AND column_c LIKE 'grapes%'
ORDER BY column_b;

Is there a way to simplify this statement to get my desired outcome of 2 and 3 based on my sample data? Or is there another way to write it?

This is poor design and should not be setup this way for many reasons (one you are seeing now).  You can/should run some process to parse out that column into another table that references this main table.  So new table would have FK relationship to ColumnA  and have Column C values parsed out  so you would have in the table 1 - apples  and 2nd row  1 - oranges.    (or even better if the values apples/oranges is limited create a lookup table and just have 2 IDs in the other table for the relationships.

Question: What's worse than a comma-separated list of values in a database? Answer: A comma-space-separated list that optionally ends with a period.

if the value in column A is listed in Column B that never happens in your sample data

Are you trying to match substrings or words, e.g. should 'apples%' match 'applesauce, grapenuts.'? Matching words adds to the complexity.

You can use the STRING_SPLIT() to separate the values in your comma-separated list and the IN (...) operator to check for a match. Because of the extra spaces and possible trailing period in your list column, some trimming is needed to condition the extracted values to ensure a successful match.
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T
WHERE T.Column_B IN (
    SELECT TRIM(S.value)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM T.Column_C), ',') S
)

Results (with an extra test to show a match to the trailing "grapes." entry):



Column_A
Column_B
Column_C




1
apples
apples, oranges


4
grapes
apples, grapes.



If you want the rows where the Column_B values are not in the Column_C list, change the IN to a NOT IN. Results (with extra test data) would then be:



Column_A
Column_B
Column_C




2
oranges
apples, grapes.


3
grapes
oranges, apples


5
apples
grapes, pineapples.



The above works in SQL Server 2022 and later. In earlier versions that do not support the TRIM(TRAILING ...) syntax, you may need to just use REPLACE(T.Column_C, '.', '') or some other technique to eliminate the trailing period. For even older versions (2016), you need to replace TRIM(...) with LTRIM(RTRIM(...)). If you are using  a version older than that, you should really consider an upgrade. You are past the product end of support. (See SQL Server lifecycle dates.)
A simplified match condition WHERE T.Column_C LIKE '%' + T.Column_B + '%' may be tempting and will seem to work for many cases, but is can lead to false matches, such as matching "apples" with "pineapples". A more complicated expression that enforces starting and ending delimiters is possible, but it gets tricky with your list syntax - WHERE ', ' + TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM T.Column_C) + ', ' LIKE '%, ' + T.Column_B + ', %'.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo that shows several options.

This worked! thank you very much!

@Tayylor - Don't forget to accept the answer, and also upvote any other answers that were helpful.

This can definitely be simplified, if you use the STRING_SPLIT function:
SELECT * FROM MyTable
LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(MyTable.Column_C, ',') AS c
    ON LTRIM(RTRIM(c.value)) = MyTable.Column_B
WHERE c.value IS NULL
ORDER BY MyTable.Column_B;

Here, STRING_SPLIT(MyTable.Column_C) splits the values in Column C into individual rows based on the comma delimiter, and then all the whitespace is trimmed off. By using a left join, you get all the rows from your table, along with the matching split values from Column C. If there’s no match, the result will include a NULL for that split value. The WHERE c.value IS NULL clause filters the results to only include rows from MyTable where the value in Column B does not exist in the split values from Column C.

For some reason when I use string_split(MyTable.Column_C) i am getting a multi-part identifier could not be bound error.

Please try the following solution using tokenization via SQL Server's XML and XQuery.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY clause is tokenizing the col_b column value
containing a list of comma separated tokens. Number of tokens is "unlimited".
XQuery .exist() method is checking if any of tokens is equal to the
col_a column value.

At the end, just uncomment the WHERE clause to get the desired result.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col_a VARCHAR(30), col_b VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (col_a, col_b) VALUES
('apples',  'apples, oranges'),
('oranges', 'apples, grapes'),
('grapes',  'oranges, apples, bananas');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(2) = ', ';

SELECT *
    , c.exist('/root/r[text()=sql:column("col_a")]') AS result -- just to see
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(col_b, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
--WHERE c.exist('/root/r[text()=sql:column("col_a")]') = 0; -- or 1

Output



id
col_a
col_b
result




1
apples
apples, oranges
1


2
oranges
apples, grapes
0


3
grapes
oranges, apples, bananas
0



